# Postgres - select, order and combine results

Tags: postgresql

In an app I am writing I am automatically generating a "callsign" for each user when they first register with the server.  The callsign bears the format `adjective adjective creature`.  The underlying Postgres tables from which I pick these values are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE adjectives ("adj" character varying(16) NOT NULL,"quality" smallint NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "adjectives_adj_key" UNIQUE ("adj")) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO adjectives (adj,quality) VALUES ('bold',1),('witty',1),('red',5),('old',3);

CREATE TABLE creatures ("creature" character varying(16) NOT NULL,"quality" smallint NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "creatures_creature_key" UNIQUE ("creature")) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO creatures (creature,quality) VALUES ('tiger',1),('dog',1),('sparrow',5), 
('dolphin',3);
```

When generating a new callsign I need to do the following

- Pick two adjectives and a creature at random from their respective tables
- Order the adjectives in ascending order of quality.  In order to respect the rules of English grammar I need the right adjective order.  `Big Red Bull`, for instance is right.  `Red Big Bull` is not.
- I need to check that the generated call sign does not already exist in the users table shown below

```
CREATE TABLE users ("user" character varying(16) NOT NULL,"callsign CHARACTER VARYING(32) NOT NULL);
```

The users table has much else - I have trimmed the details.

While I can work with basic SQL selects and do the rest in server-side script I suspect that there is a smart SQL only way of doing much, if not all, of the above in order to generate a unique, grammatically valid callsign.  My rather limited knowledge of SQL is not quite up to that task.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to code this is to get the Cartesian product of `adjectives` X `adjectives` X `creatures`, remove the ones already used, and then select a random one from the list:

```
select concat(
         a1.adj, ' ',
         a2.adj, ' ',
         c.creature
       )
  from adjectives a1
       join adjectives a2
         on a2.quality >= a1.quality
       cross join creatures c
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from users
                    where callsign = concat(
                                       a1.adj, ' ',
                                       a2.adj, ' ',
                                       c.creature))
 order by random()
 limit 1
;
```

If you do not want to allow doubled `adjective` values, then change the inequality to `>` instead of `>=`.

This will not scale well if you get into hundreds of `adjectives` and `creatures`, but I cannot think of how to avoid a Cartesian product unless we bring iteration into the solution.

[Working fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bSjwHNFLDGBcaypXAZieAj/0)

Comment: Thank you!  That works perfectly.  I currently have a list of around 300 adjectives & creatures.  To deal with the issue of scale I will probably take out the `limit 1` and store part result set  (say 50 results) in Redis.  That way I avoid having to run this SQL for each user registration.  A CRON job can watch Redis and repopulate it with fresh callsigns periodically.